# SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database

Tags: sql-server-2008

We keep getting the error SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database in our environment.

We are sure the connectionstring used is correct. The user has the necessary permissions in the database and we cannot see any signs the database is offline in any way.

Any hints on why this error may occur? What to look for using extended events?

The application where this problem occurs has a few clients that connect to a service. This service runs on the same server as the database. The database has synchronous mirroring set up. There are no signs of failover when the problem occur.

There are no other apps that connect to the database. We have so far not been able to catch the error while it is happening, but the users succeed with their task if they retry a minute later.

The connection string used: 
Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=xyz; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Transaction Binding=Explicit Unbind; Connect Timeout=5;

Full exception:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database xyz requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\XYZUSER.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Adapdev.Data.ConnectionScope.get_Connection()
   at Adapdev.Data.AbstractDAO`2.CreateCommand(String command)
   at NAFData.FarmaPro.DAL.DAO.BetalingsBetingelseDAO.GetCommandForCriteria(Criteria`1 criteria)
   at NAFData.FarmaPro.BusinessLayer.Kunde.KundeClassFactory.FetchBetalingsBetingelse(Int64 sessionId, Criteria`1 betalingsBetingelseCriteria)

Many thanks for any help.

Best regards,
Vemund Haga

Comment: Can you show the connection string? Can other apps connect to the database? Can you connect to the database via SSMS?

Comment: Is `SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database` the _entire_ error message? or is there more? If more, please post the rest of it.